# Extracting information from an event log data

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract a specific piece of information from a from an event log data, which is text file format. Below is a sample data for your reference. The idea is to extract X and Y measurements from this data. Sample provided below.

```
text ="65097    3785    <00>    tag KV-C203 fmt 65  typ KVMAxLOG:WM_area_results_table  dat <0A>    
 <0B>   stroke  0   area_results    <0B>    area_centre_xy  <0B>    x   -0.1279636  y   0.0819952   
 <00>   plane_deviation 0   area_id 10  area_measurement_ok TRUE    plane_deviation_check_done  
 FALSE  plane_deviation_check_ok    FALSE   FSM_check_ok    FALSE   FSM_check_done  FALSE   
 leveling_method    LEVELING_METHOD_TRADITIONAL <00>    x_gridlines_shift   0   nr_of_x_gridlines 
 5  nr_of_y_gridlines   38  <00>    <0B>    stroke  0   area_results    <0B>    area_centre_xy  <0B>
 x  -0.1279636  y   0.04919712  <00>    plane_deviation 0   area_id 9   area_measurement_ok TRUE    
 plane_deviation_check_done FALSE   plane_deviation_check_ok    FALSE   FSM_check_ok    FALSE   
 FSM_check_done FALSE   leveling_method LEVELING_METHOD_TRADITIONAL <00>    
 x_gridlines_shift  0   nr_of_x_gridlines   9   nr_of_y_gridlines   61  <00>    <0B>    
 stroke 0   area_results    <0B>    area_centre_xy  <0B>    x   -0.1279636  y   0.01639904  <00>    
 plane_deviation    0   area_id 8   area_measurement_ok TRUE    plane_deviation_check_done  FALSE   
 plane_deviation_check_ok   FALSE   FSM_check_ok    FALSE   FSM_check_done  FALSE   leveling_method 
 LEVELING_METHOD_TRADITIONAL    <00>    x_gridlines_shift   0   nr_of_x_gridlines   9   
 nr_of_y_gridlines  61  <00>    <0B>    stroke  0   area_results    <0B>    area_centre_xy  <0B>    
 x  -0.1279636  y   -0.01639904 <00>    plane_deviation 0   area_id 7   area_measurement_ok TRUE    
 plane_deviation_check_done FALSE   plane_deviation_check_ok    FALSE   FSM_check_ok    FALSE   
 FSM_check_done FALSE   leveling_method LEVELING_METHOD_TRADITIONAL <00>    x_gridlines_shift   
 0  nr_of_x_gridlines   9   nr_of_y_gridlines   61  <00>    <0B>    stroke  0   area_results    
 <0B>   area_centre_xy  <0B>    x   -0.1279636  y   -0.04919712 <00>    plane_deviation 0   
 area_id    6   area_measurement_ok TRUE    plane_deviation_check_done  FALSE   
 plane_deviation_check_ok   FALSE   FSM_check_ok    FALSE   FSM_check_done  FALSE   
 leveling_method    LEVELING_METHOD_TRADITIONAL <00>    x_gridlines_shift   0   nr_of_x_gridlines   
 9  nr_of_y_gridlines   61  <00>    <0B>    stroke  0   area_results    <0B>    area_centre_xy  
 <0B>   x   -0.1279636  y   -0.0819952  <00>    plane_deviation 0   area_id 5   
 area_measurement_ok    TRUE    plane_deviation_check_done  FALSE   plane_deviation_check_ok    
 FALSE  FSM_check_ok    FALSE   FSM_check_done  FALSE   leveling_method 
 LEVELING_METHOD_TRADITIONAL    <00>    x_gridlines_shift   0   nr_of_x_gridlines   
 5  nr_of_y_gridlines   38  <00>    <00>    <00>    \n  None    None    None    None    
 None   None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None    None"
```

expected output

```
x             y
-0.1279636   0.0819952
-0.1279636   0.04919712
-0.1279636   0.01639904
-0.1279636  -0.01639904
-0.1279636  -0.04919712
-0.1279636  -0.0819952
```

Comment: The example provided is just one line of a text in a text file. I have to go through several thousands of lines and extract x and y values in the same text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

for x,y in re.findall('x\s+(-?\d\.\d+)\s+y\s+(-?\d\.\d+)',text):
   print(x, y)
```

Result:

```
-0.1279636 0.0819952
-0.1279636 0.04919712
-0.1279636 0.01639904
-0.1279636 -0.01639904
-0.1279636 -0.04919712
-0.1279636 -0.0819952
```

If you read in the text line by line into `sample` and want to store the data in a data frame:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y'])

for text in sample:
   a = re.findall('x\s+(-?\d\.\d+)\s+y\s+(-?\d\.\d+)',text)
   df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['x','y']))
```

`findall` will return strings, if you need numbers you'll have to specify the `dtype`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x','y'], dtype=float)

for text in sample:
   a = re.findall('x\s+(-?\d\.\d+)\s+y\s+(-?\d\.\d+)',text)
   df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['x','y'], dtype=float))
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I am reading the text file line by line into an array file sample = [], now I would like run the same logic on that entire array. I am getting an error, do you have an any suggestion to make it  work?

Comment: I am running the same code on the sample array. for x,y in re.findall('x\s+(-?\d\.\d+)\s+y\s+(-?\d\.\d+)',sample):
   print(x, y)              TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: import re
for text in sample:
    for x,y in re.findall('x\s+(-?\d\.\d+)\s+y\s+(-?\d\.\d+)',text):
        print(x, y)  ---------------is this something like this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196397/discussion-between-vishwas-and-stef).

Answer (score 2):

If this is a hard code method to find just x' and y's then it can be easily achieved as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['x'] = re.findall('x\s+([+-]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+)', text)
df['y'] = re.findall('y\s+([+-]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+)', text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the data structure is here, but this code will extract them from this specific string. I am sure if other instances of this are somewhat similar this should also work.

```py
xvals = []
yvals = []
split1 = text.split("<00>")
for item1 in split1:
    split2 = item1.split("<0B>")
    for item2 in split2:
        split3 = [x for x in item2.split(" ") if x != ""]
        if "x" in split3 and "y" in split3:
            xvals.append(float(split3[split3.index("x")+1]))
            yvals.append(float(split3[split3.index("y")+1]))

print(xvals)
print(yvals)
```

Outputs:

```py
[-0.1279636, -0.1279636, -0.1279636, -0.1279636, -0.1279636, -0.1279636] #x_vals
[0.0819952, 0.04919712, 0.01639904, -0.01639904, -0.04919712, -0.0819952] #y_vals
```

Comment: Probably a waste of time to attempt to answer a question like this. Once you gain more rep, you can vote to close as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, this answer only addresses the text posted in the question. OP will have to carefully consider how to generalize the regex depending on what kind of variations he/she may be expecting to run this regex on.

```
import re
x = re.findall( r' x *?([\-0-9\.]+)', text )
y = re.findall( r' y *?([\-0-9\.]+)', text )
print( x )
print( y )
```

Basically, the `re.findall` searches for all matches within the parenthesis of the pattern. Since it looks like the example text always leads with "[space]x[space]..." and "[space]y[space]...", you can create a pattern searching for this and only matching number characters (negative signs, 0-9 digits, and decimal points).

One more note, you can encase the large `text` block within triple quotes (""") so that you don't have to deal with new lines. For example:

```
text = """start of text
words on new line
more words on new line"""
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, this work on one line of text, which is the sample data I provided. Now I want to apply the same logic on the entire text file, which I am reading it line by line to an empty array. I appreciate if you have any suggestions on how to go about it.